# Bisectors and equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have the following problem: bisectors $AA',BB'$ and $CC'$ of the triangle $ABC$ intersect the circumcircle in the points $A",B",C".$ Holds the following equivalence: $\frac{AA'}{AA"}+\frac{BB'}{BB"}+\frac{CC'}{CC"}=\frac{9}{4}$equivalent triangle $ABC $ equilateral?

Comment: Your last line is not clear.

Comment: if the relation holds, then the triangle is equivalent and conversely if the triangle is equivalent, then that relation holds

Comment: Its equivalent to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989362/proving-a-triangle-equilateral-given-condition-al-a2bl-b2cl-c2-9r-delta so there's your proof :D

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In case you requested to prove $$\frac{AA_1}{AA_2}+\frac{BB_1}{BB_2}+\frac{CC_1}{CC_2}=\frac{9}{4} \iff \Delta ABC \text{ is equilateral }$$

1. $ABC \text{ is equilateral }$
   This case is quite trivial, as $\frac{AA_1}{AA_2}=\frac{BB_1}{BB_2}=\frac{CC_1}{CC_2}=\frac{r+\frac{r}{2}}{2r}=\frac34$, thus $\frac{AA_1}{AA_2}+\frac{BB_1}{BB_2}+\frac{CC_1}{CC_2}=3\frac34=\frac94$
2. $\frac{AA_1}{AA_2}+\frac{BB_1}{BB_2}+\frac{CC_1}{CC_2}=\frac{9}{4}$
   Consider second picture:
   [image]

We can state:
$$BA_2=2R\sin\angle BAA_2=2R\sin\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)$$
$$\angle BA_1A_2 = \pi-(A_1BA_2 + BA_2A)=\pi-\frac{\angle BAC}{2}-\angle ACB=\frac{\angle BAC}{2}+\angle ABC$$
Thus by the *law of sines* you get $$\frac{BA_2}{\angle BA_1A_2}=\frac{A_2A-A_1A}{\sin\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}\\\frac{2R\sin\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}+\angle ABC\right)}=\frac{A_2A-A_1A}{\sin\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}$$
Thus
$$A_2A-A_1A=\frac{2R\sin^2\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}+\angle ABC\right)}$$
and since the length of the angle bisector is known to be $$A_1=\frac{2AB\cdot AC\cos\left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}{AB+AC}$$
you can find the ratio $\frac{AA_1}{AA_2}$. Reiterate for the other sides and you get the final expression, where most of the length of the sides will get simplified.

Comment: can you expand case 2?

Comment: I was writing... ;)

Comment: I'm curious what you have obtained for that ratio and how the length sides simplify so easy! Thank you for your effort!

Comment: So, what is the ratio at the end?

Comment: I was working to find the ratio expressed in a nice way, but couldn't reach a beautiful expression where the lengths of the sides simplify

Comment: Please, share your sum of $$\frac{AA_1}{AA_2}+\frac{BB_1}{BB_2}+\frac{CC_1}{CC_2}$$...

Comment: From $AA_2-AA_1= \frac{2Rsin^2(\angle BAC/2){sin(\angle BAC/2+\angle ABC)}$ and the relation for $AA_1$ we get an ugly expression for $AA_2$ then, dividing $AA_1$ by $AA_2$ we obtain the ratio: \frac{2AB*AC*cos(\angle BAC/2) sin(\angle BAC/2+\angle ABC){(AB+AC)2Rsin^2(\angle BAC/2)*2AB*AC*.......(and cos of angle Bac/2 multiplipied by sin of bac/2+abc). That's not nice

Comment: I obtained the ratio in another way and reached the conclusion.

Comment: oook :), would you like to share your alternative method?

Comment: I have only my iPad now, so I can't write the solution. Anyways, I'm still interested on the ratio which you obtained. if you obtained a nice ratio, then you MUST show it to me because it's a nice idea how you approached it and I would like to see a complete solution! I writ my solution when I return back home.